# How to select descendent elements previously filtered with :not or .not()

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

Guess the following body snippet of HTML DOM:

```
...
<div class="entry">
    <div class="evil">
        <div class="some-other-class">
            <pre>My foo text</pre>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="entry">
    <div class="nice">
        <pre>My nice text</pre>
    </div>
</div>
...
```

Using jQuery I want to select all `<pre>` elements that belong to a parent element of type `div.entry` and *are not a descendent* of a `div.evil`. More precisely: I want to apply a specific class to those "non-evil" `<pre>`-elements only.

I used the `:not` selector filter as well as the `.not()` method for building a chain for selecting appropriate subsets and descendent elements before applying the class as shown here:

```
$("div.entry div:not(.evil) pre").addClass("pretty");
```

And alternatively:

```
$("div.entry").not("div.evil").find("pre").addClass("pretty")
```

Both variants resulting in *matching all `pre` elements* including the ones with an "evil" parent div!

However when I select a direct parent plus class and child like this:

```
$("div.entry div:not(.some-other-class) > pre").addClass("pretty");
```

it works like expected. First I thought I misunderstood descendent element selection using `element1 element2`. Using the chained filter methods without success though proved that something else must be wrong.

The problem itself doesn't sound hard but it now drives me nuts.

Any ideas if and why my way of selecting might be wrong?

Comment: Do you mean `div.post` or `div.entry`. Because I don't see class `.post` in your HTML.

Comment: Of course I mean `div.entry`. Typo. Will correct that now.

Comment: Thank you guys for some great answers and elegant ways to solve this problem! Just for getting it completely and right: Is my way of filtering with `not:` _not_ allowed in combination with descendent element selection? In my understanding the selected subset of `div:not(.evil)` should return all descendent div elements of `div.entry` that don't match class `evil`. Damned, what the hell I'm getting wrong?

Comment: Here you go. Check my answer out and get rid of the bad div!

Comment: If you are satisfied, please consider to flag my answer as accepted :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Keep it simple:

```
$('div.entry pre:not(div.evil pre)');
```

Here you go: [jsfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jxvCG/)

**Note**

So, why

```
$("div.entry div:not(.evil) pre");
```

does not work?

When you ask for `div:not(.evil)`, the jQuery guy will return you `div.some-other-class` as well as `div.nice`, so that the final selector would be:

```
$("div.entry div.some-other-class pre, div.entry div.nice pre");
```

which match even the `pre` which are descendant of the bad, bad, `div.evil`!

Comment: A bit weird logic. And what if you have many `.evil` elements?

Comment: So it is not that weird after all ;) Thanks for your +1!

Comment: And that also surprised me ;)

Answer (score 3):

I'd suggest:

```
$('div.entry pre').filter(function(){
    return !$(this).closest('div.evil').length
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/YQarr/).

The advantages, for me, are that you simply select *all* `pre` elements, and then reduce those elements based on a (fairly) simple parent-assessment. Alternative approaches work just as well, this is just...my personal preference.

Comment: It's better to use `$("div.entry pre")` selector here.

Comment: Don't forget he wanted `I want to select all <pre> elements that belong to a parent element of type div.entry`  adding that in the selector should work

Answer (score 2):

You can use `:has` selector:

```
$("div.entry:not(:has(.evil)) pre").addClass("pretty");
```

http://jsfiddle.net/7BNQN/

Or:

```
$('div.entry').not(':has(.evil)').find('pre').addClass("pretty");
```